# BroadcastReceiver doesn't trigger with custom process name

Tags: android

I try to listen on Calendar and Contacts event change so I created Service and BroadcastReceiver, see `Manifest.xml`:

```
        <service android:name="com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.sample.TheService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.sample.TheService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="com.my.the.TheBroadcastReceiver" android:priority="1000" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:host="com.android.calendar" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.my.the.BroadcastReceiverContacts" android:priority="1000" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CONTENT_CHANGED" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:host="com.android.calendar" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

After several hours OS kills my service and my application stoops listen on events change. So I created some WatchDog:

```
            <receiver android:name="com.my.the.service.WatcherReceiver" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
                    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
```

but when I try to set custom process name (`android:process=":theService"`)it stops listen.

```
        <service android:name="com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.sample.TheService" android:process=":theService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.sample.TheService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="com.my.the.TheBroadcastReceiver" android:priority="1000" android:process=":theService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:host="com.android.calendar" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.my.the.BroadcastReceiverContacts" android:priority="1000" android:process=":theService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CONTENT_CHANGED" />
                <data android:scheme="content" />
                <data android:host="com.android.calendar" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.my.the.service.WatcherReceiver" android:process=":serviceWatcher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_OKAY" />
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

How to solve this problem,

please help,

Comment: are the broadcast receivers LocalBroadcastReceivers?

Comment: @Roadblock no, they come from Android Calendar/Contacts. It works only when I use default process (no field `android:process`)

Comment: So you when remove the android:process tag from receivers only and keep them in service, the receivers can still start the service running under android:process?

Comment: hi can you tell us why you did created the broadcast receiver with custom remote process name , ideally when you declare the broadcast receiver under the android manifest it will definitely receive event even if your application  is not in front. In short simply create the broadcast receiver and listen the event. one more point what about the service. what it does in your application, why you create the service, can you elaborate about it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the service running in a seprate process does not listen to Broadcast sent in the same process but will respond when the Broadcasts are global. You will have to check the implementation. I am not sure about the exact reasons for such a behavior. Preferably avoid sending a broadcast in a process when you want to interact with a service. Send a global broadcast instead.

Answer (score -1):

If Android OS kills your service, try to start it in foreground, so you can prevent it from being killed. You can use [`startForeground(int id, Notification notification)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29) method available in `Service` class. You can read about [Running a Service in the Foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) in official Android API Guide. In addition, you can find sample project using `startForeground()` method in this repository: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/.

Comment: its not answer on my question. After adding `android:process=":theService"` receiver stops listen

Comment: Do you need to add this?

Comment: I try to understand why when I define custom process, broadcast receiver doesn't work

Comment: In Android OS each app runs as a separate process. I don't have experience with creating service with "process" attribute, but if Android really creates separate process for the Service with such attribute, probably BroadcastReceiver listens only events in its own (app's) process and doesn't receive events from different processes. That's why you may not be able to receive an Intent in your BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: you can notice that service and broadcast receiver have the same process (see Manifest)